# Django: How to you organise static pages in apps?

Tags: python, django, static

Its said to keep each functionality as an app and keep it as pluggable as possible.

So,
How do you organise pages like :

- **Homepage**
- **About Us**
- **Contact Us**
- **etc**

These are not exactly functionality, so does django devs manage these ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just use flatpages app: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/flatpages/ and have one template for them.

Comment: Interesting.. But what if you have dynamic content in these pages ?
I want to know how do you organize these pages in apps appropriately ?

Comment: Then you are close to the point where a dedicated CMS (FeinCMS etc.) makes sense. FeinCMS has a very practical feature called content types: http://packages.python.org/FeinCMS/contenttypes.html#what-is-a-content-type-anyway

So the general idea is that your (general) pages are containers that combine data from different apps. And that's the way I'd look a it, not the other way around ("organizing pages in apps").

Comment: If you use flatpages, you shoudn't care about apps because they are just records in DB, edited via Django admin. If you need to pass some dynamic content than look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/ and I would put them to the separate app all together. Also, I don't think that you will share them with other people or between projects, so you shouldn't care about creating a reusable app for them.

Comment: +1 for : So the general idea is that your (general) pages are containers that combine data from different apps. And that's the way I'd look a it, not the other way around ("organizing pages in apps")

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Django Flat Pages](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/flatpages/?from=olddocs).

Comment: Interesting.. But what if you have dynamic content in these pages ?
I want to know how do you organize these pages in apps appropriately ?

Answer (score 0):

I put them in a 'business' app. I feel there is no need to overthink it really.

Comment: Hm.. I also thought the same way. I have them in a content app right now.